# Two measures on a same space

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I have two measure space $(X, S, \mu_1)$ and $(X, S,\mu_2)$,
where $S$ is the minimal $\sigma$-algebra 
containing sets $T = \{E_i\}_{i \in I}$. 
Suppose further that $T$ is closed under taking finite intersections. Also $\mu_1(X) = \mu_2(X) < \infty$.
Suppose it is the case that 
$$
\mu_{1}(E) \geq \mu_2(E)
$$
for all $E \in T$. Does it follow that
$$
\mu_{1}(E) \geq \mu_2(E)
$$
for all $E \in S$?
If this is not true, I would also appreciate related known results.
Thanks!

Comment: I think there's a lemma about the uniqueness if $\{E_i\}$ s are stable under finite intersection

Comment: As a very bad counterexample, you could set $\mu_1(E)=2\mu_2(E)=|E|$ where $|E|$ denotes the cardinality of the set $E$ and let $\{E_i\}_{i\in I}$ denotes the standard topology of $\mathbb{R}$, that is, the collection of all open intervals. Note that $S$ would contain finite sets for which the second inequality is no longer true.

Comment: I see. Thank you for the comments. I realized I had to be more specific with this question, and I have changed the question accordingly. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X=\{0,1\}$, $\mathcal{S}=2^X$, and let $\mu_1=\delta_0$, the probability measure concentrated on $0$, and $\mu_2=\delta_1$ the probability measure concentrated on $1$. Let $T=\{0\}$. Then the assumptions are satisfied, yet $\mu_2(\{1\})>\mu_1(\{0\})$.

If such a result would hold under some additional assumptions, one would get $\mu_1=\mu_2$, since both $\mu_1(E)\geq\mu_2(E)$ and $\mu_1(X\backslash E)\geq\mu_2(X\backslash E)$ would have to hold for all $E\in\mathcal{S}$, which implies under the assumption that $\mu_1(X)=\mu_2(X)<\infty$ that $\mu_1(E)=\mu_2(E)$ for all $E\in\mathcal{S}$.